# Gson deserialize object or array

Tags: android, gson

I got json string like:

```
{
"currentPage": 1,
"dataList": [
    {
        "date": 1395110482,
        "imageList": [
            "http://www.timeface.cn/uploads/times/2014/01/26/15/4209_YJgMNq.jpg",
            "http://www.timeface.cn/uploads/times/2014/01/26/15/4209_YJgMNq.jpg"
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": 1395110482,
        "imageList": [
            "http://www.timeface.cn/uploads/times/2014/01/26/15/0449_kZyFc4.jpg"
        ]
    }

    ],
    "info": "ok",
    "status": "1",
    "totalPage": 1
}
```

And my bean is

```
public class TimeSetList extends BaseResponse
{
    public int currentPage;
    public int totalPage;
    public List<TimeSet> dataList;

}


public class TimeSet extends BaseModule
{    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String date;
    public List<String> imageUrl;

}
```

My question is the param imageList, it contains one or more string object.
How to deal with this problem？

thanks

Comment: have you tried deserializing it already and received an error?

Comment: I use ArrayList instead, and that's all you need. GSON will understand it's an array, and it can contains 0 o mores Strings.

Comment: imageList is an ARRAY in JSON there (denoted by []), not "one or more string object." For that you use a Collection in Java (List<String>). It looks like you already got that far though. However, you used the name "imageUrl" instead of "imageList" in the TimeSet class so GSON is not going to be able to associate those automatically (you can rename the field or use an annotation like @SerializedName("imageList")).